# Generate multiple OpenOffice pages from a one-page template

Tags: python, libreoffice

I have a one-page OpenOffice document which is a [POD](http://appyframework.org/pod.html) template. Basically, I use this template to replace tags in the template with automatically generated data in the rendered document.

This is how it works:

```
# loads the POD OpenOffice template engine
from appy.pod.renderer import Renderer as OORenderer

# defines data for template tags
ctx = {'template_tag': 'my_data'}

# renders the template in my_model.odt using defined data
r = OORenderer('my_model.odt', ctx, 'rendered_file.pdf')

# saves into the specified PDF file
r.run()
```

I would like to generate several pages like that, and merge them into a single PDF file.

Is there a way to do it using POD?

Or maybe can I programmatically merge generated PDF files into a single file?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> > and merge them into a single PDF file.

just try [pyPDF](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/).

A Pure-Python library built as a PDF toolkit. It is capable of:

- extracting document information (title, author, ...),
- splitting documents page by page,
- merging documents page by page,
- cropping pages,
- merging multiple pages into a single page,
- encrypting and decrypting PDF files.

Comment: Unfortunately not what I asked, even if it could do the job. PS I am not the one to have voted down. I didn't vote.